# Open NSWindow from xib while using storyboards and swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, xib, nswindow

I am using storyboards and swift.
Now I am trying to open a new NSWindow which is packed inside a xib file. (I've created a new xib file which contains a NSWindow)

I've added the following code to my project, but it does not open any window.

```
let controller = NSWindowController(windowNibName: "xibFile")
controller.showWindow(self)
```

I am sure I'm doing something wrong as

```
print(controller.window?.title)
```

also won't give me the correct window title from the xib file.

Hope anyone can give a hint what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Does your xib window has custom class or just NSWindowController?

Where did you trigger `controller.showWindow(self)`? Is that inside AppDelegate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second nib:

```
class SecondNibController: NSWindowController {
    override var windowNibName: String? {
        return "SecondNib" // no extension .xib here
    }
}
```

Remember to connect the `window` outlet of `SecondNibConntroller` to your window.

In your main storyboard:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    let secondNibController = SecondNibController()

    @IBAction func openSecondWindow(sender : AnyObject) {
        secondNibController.showWindow(nil)
    }
}
```